# Launch4j exe crashed silently or can't execute

Tags: java, javafx, executable-jar, launch4j

Running the compiled executable jar with `java --module-path {$SDK_PATH} add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml, javafx.media -jar frogger.jar` is fine. However, executing the compiled exe from launch4j will not run or crashed silently I would say. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here? Is there any way to see the error?

I've copied and pasted the unzipped jre in bundled directory. So I'm guessing the issue is either my launch4j configuration in build.gradle is wrong or the jre version is wrong.

the jre that I pasted in is `AdoptOpenJDK windows x64 jdk-15.0.1+9`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'application'
    id 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.9'
}

group 'com.tsb'
version '1.0'
mainClassName = 'com.tsb.frogger.core.Launcher'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

javafx {
    version = '15'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.media']
}

task myJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "$mainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

launch4j {
//    headerType = "console"
    mainClassName = "$mainClassName"
    icon = "${projectDir}/icons/frogger.ico"
    bundledJrePath = "jre"
    bundledJre64Bit = true
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the [`Console` header type](https://i.imgur.com/7VSnjfY.png)? That should let you see the output so you can see if there are any exceptions.

Comment: The problem is that it opens and closes instantly when the console is enabled.

Comment: Launch the application from the command line (with console enabled). Either redirect the standard and error output to a file or include arguments so that the application uses the same console as the one you launched it from (e.g. in PowerShell you'd include `-NoNewWindow -Wait`).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using launch4j, I recommend that you take a look at jpackage, which is available in JDK 14 and 15.  See [Packaging Tool User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/jpackage/packaging-overview.html).  Note that for Windows you will also need to download the [WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/).